# How to apply if an element is visible scrolling?

Tags: html-framework-7

How to apply if an element is visible scrolling?
but event scroll not

this my code

```
$$(document).on('scroll', '.page-content', function()
{
    console.log('scroll');
});
```

but the scroll event does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In framework7 if you want to detect scrolling on page content you need to add scroll event on that particular div.

```
<div class="page-content index-page-content"></div>
```

On this div page-content class is important.So JS should be

```
$$('.index-page-content').on('scroll',function(e){console.log("scroll happened");});
```

Try this one.It will work.Hope this helps